# Tomcat issue, inconsistent NoClassDefFoundError exceptions

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I have a somewhat baffling issue running a webapp in Apache Tomcat.

After deploying the page works fine, but sometime during the day, a page inevitably fails to compile.

The issue is not with the page itself, the page changes daily, which page seems to be determined by the order/frequency of access.

If nobody has accessed the log page during the day, that's the page that will break down.
If the log page has been accessed, it will keep on working until the next deploy, but another page page will break down.

By break down i mean:
http://codepad.org/V1yosH8k (jsp, more prevailant)
Stacktrace: http://codepad.org/P9VpXBRW (java)

ClassNotFoundException/NoClassDefFoundError: Obviously the class does exist, it works fine if accessed early after deploy.
It happens on the live server, but am unable to reproduce it on my dev machine.

Running apache tomcat 6 with JAVA_OPTS "-Xms1024m -Xmx1900m -XX:NewSize=256m -XX:MaxNewSize=256m -XX:PermSize=768m -XX:MaxPermSize=768m"

Anyone able to give me a push in the right direction?

Comment: A class is defined by both its name and the classloader used to load it. Combining this with statics can cause a lot of funny errors when classes are loaded and unloaded. See e.g. https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html

Comment: Is Tomcat, and particularly the work directory installed entirely on the local file system? Are any network file systems in use for this installation?

Comment: Everything is run locally.
If it wasn't for the lack of a permgen space error, I'd say it was memory related. But as is.. I'm at a loss.

Comment: Lowered permgen space to 512mb, seems to have fixed the problem.
(For whatever inexplicable reason)